# Get the line that appears before the matching line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use a `for` loop over `findstr` results. I want to make var6 the WHOLE line that is above found string `Class=!var4!`.  I put `skip=-1` but that doesn't work (to look backwards one line).

So if it looks like this:

```
Name=Bismark #14
Class=var4
```

I'd like var6 = Name=Bismarck #14

```
findstr /b "Class=!var4!" "PosTime_Campaign_SCR.mis"
if not errorlevel 1 (
for /f "skip=-1 delims=" %%L in ('findstr "Class=!var4!" PosTime_Campaign_SCR.mis') do (
if not errorlevel 1 (
set var6=!var6!%%L
)
)
)
```

I'm close but I don't know how to tell the `for` loop to look one line above the found string of `findstr`.

Solution:

```
@echo off

set var4=BBBismarck

for /f "delims=" %%L in (PosTime_Campaign_SCR.mis) do (
if /i "%%L" equ "Class=%var4%" (
    goto endloop
)
set "var6=%%L"
)
    :endloop

echo %var6%
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be tough to use `findstr` for that job.

I can see one approach:  use the `/N` option so `findstr` writes out the line number, then use that line number in another loop where you process one line at a time of the file and set `var6` to the previous line.

But if you're looping over every line in the file anyway, you may be better off skipping `findstr` completely and just doing your own comparisons.  Or using `findstr` on each line.

Here's some completely untested code to describe what I'm imagining:

```
for /f %%L in (PosTime_Campaign_SCR.mis) do (
    if /i "%%L" equ "Class=%var4%" (
        goto endloop
    )
    set "var6=%%L"
)
:endloop

echo %var6%
```

What we're doing here is setting `var6` to each line, but when we reach the line we want we skip out of the loop.  Therefore `var6` ends up being set to the value of the previous line.

Comment: Hi There. Almost have it. It returns part of the line above, but not the whole line. The lines may have spaces in them. So with the code you provided and my example it would return only `Name=Bismark` and not `Name=Bismark #14`

Comment: very smart and easy code. It's fast too. But how to include the spaces and the special characters like # on the line?

Answer (score 0):

```
(set var6=)
for /f "delims=" %%L in (PosTime_Campaign_SCR.mis) do IF NOT DEFINED var6 (
echo %%L | findstr "Class=!var4!" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (set var6=!lastline!)
set lastline=%%L
)
```

...assuming that Class=var4 can never appear on the first line of the file.

`lastline` holds the contents of the last line read. When the FINDSTR detects the matching line, var6 is set to the contents of the previous line read, and since var6 is now set in the environment, the check is not repeated so it sets var6 to the contents of the line before the FIRST matching line.

If you remove the `IF NOT DEFINED var6` then var6 will be set to the contents of the line before the LAST matching line.

and if var6 is undefined after execution, there was NO matching line.